# Enviando arquivo via FTP em C#, erro de URI

Tags: c#

Estou tentando enviar um arquivo via ftp usando a classe abaixo:

```
public static void EnviarArquivoFTP(string arquivo, string url, string usuario, string senha)
{
    try
    {
        FileInfo arquivoInfo = new FileInfo(arquivo);

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.ContentLength = arquivoInfo.Length;

        using (FileStream fs = arquivoInfo.OpenRead())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytesSent = 0;
            int bytes = 0;

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                while (bytesSent < arquivoInfo.Length)
                {
                    bytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    bytesSent += bytes;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Usando o chamado:

```
ftp.EnviarArquivoFTP(caminho, URIFTP, UsuarioFTP, SenhaFTP);
```

Aonde

caminho = "C:\dados\arquivo.zip"

URIFTP = "ftp:/127.0.0.1"

UsuarioFTP = "usr"

SenhaFTP = "123"

Sempre retornando o erro:

$exception  {"O URI solicitado é inválido para o comando de FTP."}  System.Net.WebException

Comment: Sim, rodando um local, ele dá erro de URI, não de conexao, o FileZilla Server no caso

Comment: @LuisFernandoConsuloMartins Se colocar 2 barras no lugar de 1 resolve o problema?

Comment: Não, tentei com duas e uma barra tanto na URI do FTP tanto como no diretório, mesmo erro

Comment: Tentou declarar os caminhos como strings sem caracter de escape? Assim: `caminho = @"C:\dados\arquivo.zip"; e URIFTP  = @"ftp://127.0.0.1";`

Comment: $exception {"URI inválido: esquema URI inválido."} System.UriFormatException  @DiegoRafaelSouza

Comment: Como você quer fazer o *upload* de um arquivo, você deve fornecer ao *FTPClient* o nome do arquivo. `var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://127.0.0.1/arquivo.zip");` Fonte: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ba8d3b4-e7da-4130-83bb-db1aa0c974f8/uploading-a-file-the-requested-uri-is-invalid-for-this-ftp-command?forum=netfxnetcom

Comment: O esquema é  justamente a primeira parte. Eu nao sei como esta o seu método `EnviarArquivoFtp` mas se espera string ele pode stwe fazendo o tratamento la dentro. Envia só o caminho, para ver se o esquema e a porta ele está tratando internamente : `URIFTP = @"127.0.0.1”;`.  Se não rolar, vamos precisar ver o que tem dentro desse método

Comment: Talvez deva considerar isto: https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0003.md

Comment: Conforme a documentação (https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=net-7.0) o caminho em Create deve ser o caminho completo, exemplo: `(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://foo.bar/someFile.txt"))`